# When does contractible space of almost complex structures taming a given symplectic form $\omega$ contain an integrable compatible one?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, kahler-manifolds, almost-complex

Given a symplectic form $\omega$ on a compact symplectic manifold $X$, we know there is a contractible homotopy class $\mathcal{J}_{\omega}$ of almost complex structures that tame $\omega$.  A subset of these is also compatible with $\omega$, in that $\omega(\cdot, J\cdot \cdot)$ defines a Riemannian metric on the manifold.  How do know, other than things like odd Betti numbers being even, if $\omega$ has an *integrable* member $J_{\omega, int}$ of $\mathcal{J}_{\omega}$, so that $(X,\omega, J_{\omega, int}, \omega(\cdot, J_{\omega, int}\cdot \cdot))$ is a Kaehler manifold?

Answer (score 1):

There are LOTS of additional obstructions (for example, not every finitely presented group whose abelianization has even rank is a fundamental group of a Kaehler manifold). Most of the known obstructions are listed, for example, [here](https://msp.org/gt/2018/22-4/gt-v22-n4-p04-s.pdf).